# What are the words of Galadriel at the beginning of the Fellowship?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, movie, elves, quotes

In the trilogy of the movies, at the very beginning Galadriel says a few words starting with "The World is changed. I feel it..." In the background the words start in Elvish "Yamma presta..." What are those words?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.elvish.org/gwaith/movie_fotr.htm#presta) a site that talks about linguistics in the Lord of the Rings movies. According to it, the complete line is:

> I amar prestar aen, han mathon ne nen, han mathon ne chae a han noston ned 'wilith.

which -- as you'd expect -- is a Sindarin version of Galadriel's English lines:

> 'The world is changed; I can feel it in the water, I can feel it in the earth, I can smell it in the air.'

Note that the movie gives these lines to Galadriel, but in the book, they're said by Fangorn *to* Galadriel, in a very different context: it's in chapter 6 of book VI, and

> he's lamenting the fact that, because the world is changing, the two of them will likely never meet again.

---

One further note: the attempted transcription in the OP is missing the Rs at the end of "amar" and "prestar." This can probably be traced to Cate Blanchett's [non-rhotic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhotic_and_non-rhotic_accents) Australian accent creeping into her Sindarin pronunciation; in Tolkien's elvish languages as correctly pronounced, that R should always be audibly rolled. The pronunciation chapter at the beginning of [Helge Fauskanger's Quenya course](http://folk.uib.no/hnohf/qcourse.htm) has some remarks on this kind of thing (mostly about the correct pronunciation of "Mordor").

Comment: Could you say in which context are these lines said in the book, please?

Comment: @Thecafremo, it's in Book VI chapter 6, Many Partings, around the middle of the chapter.  I don't want to include spoilers, so I won't say anything else about it.

Comment: Wow, so you're saying she speaks Elvish with an Australian accent? I don't know why but for some reason that blows my mind.

Comment: @Tacroy: At least that one feature of one? I'm not good enough with accents to comment on how Australian she sounds in general...

Comment: @Micah- Us Australians pronounce 'R's as 'Ah' when it follows an 'a', (such as 'Radar' or 'far' etc) Blanchett probably just said "Amah". I dare-say she was trying to mask her Australian accent, but little bits and pieces like this just happened to slip through

Comment: Also the bit where she said to Frodo “Welcome to Rivendell cobber! Grab a tinny and let’s throw a steak on the barbie.” seemed a bit colloquial.